# How to parse objects from a stream of json

Tags: python, json

I have a lot of json I am reading from a webpage. It cannot be read at one go as I get a memory error. So I am trying to stream it using ijson library. The problem is I lose the structure of the json so I cannot obtain the data properly and in order.

I am able to read the key value pairs etc but there is no structure anymore.

This is the code I have:

```
parser = ijson.parse(urllib.request.urlopen('https://data.medicaid.gov/resource/4qik-skk9.json?$limit=5'))
for prefix, event, value  in parser:
    print(str(prefix) +" "+str(event)+ " "+str(value))
```

This is the structure of the json:

```
[
    {
        "package_size_code": "60",
        "fda_ther_equiv_code": "NR",
        "fda_application_number": "204153",
        "clotting_factor_indicator": "N",
        "year": "2018",
        "fda_product_name": "LUZU Cream 1% 60gm",
        "labeler_name": "MEDICIS DERMATOLOGICS, INC.",
        "ndc": "99207085060",
        "product_code": "0850",
        "unit_type": "GM",
        "fda_approval_date": "2013-11-14T00:00:00",
        "market_date": "2014-03-14T00:00:00",
        "pediatric_indicator": "N",
        "package_size_intro_date": "2014-03-14T00:00:00",
        "units_per_pkg_size": "60000",
        "labeler_code": "99207",
        "desi_indicator": "1",
        "drug_category": "S",
        "quarter": "3",
        "cod_status": "3"
    },
    {
        "package_size_code": "60",
        "fda_ther_equiv_code": "AB",
        "fda_application_number": "21758",
        "clotting_factor_indicator": "N",
        "year": "2018",
        "fda_product_name": "VANOS CREAM .1%",
        "labeler_name": "MEDICIS DERMATOLOGICS, INC.",
        "ndc": "99207052560",
        "product_code": "0525",
        "unit_type": "GM",
        "fda_approval_date": "2005-02-11T00:00:00",
        "market_date": "2005-02-21T00:00:00",
        "pediatric_indicator": "N",
        "package_size_intro_date": "2005-02-21T00:00:00",
        "units_per_pkg_size": "60000",
        "labeler_code": "99207",
        "desi_indicator": "1",
        "drug_category": "I",
        "quarter": "3",
        "cod_status": "3"
    },
.
.
.
.
]
```

The output I get from using ijson is:

```
 start_array None                                           
item start_map None                                         
item map_key clotting_factor_indicator                      
item.clotting_factor_indicator string N                     
item map_key cod_status                                     
item.cod_status string 4                                    
item map_key desi_indicator                                 
item.desi_indicator string 1                                
item map_key drug_category                                  
item.drug_category string I                                 
item map_key fda_application_number                         
item.fda_application_number string 50007                    
item map_key fda_approval_date                              
item.fda_approval_date string 1990-09-30T00:00:00.000       
item map_key fda_product_name                               
item.fda_product_name string DOXYCYCLINE HYCLATE 100MG CAP  
item map_key fda_ther_equiv_code                            
item.fda_ther_equiv_code string AB                          
item map_key labeler_code                                   
item.labeler_code string 59762                              
item map_key labeler_name                                   
item.labeler_name string PFIZER, INC.                       
item map_key market_date                                    
item.market_date string 1990-09-30T00:00:00.000             
item map_key ndc                                            
item.ndc string 59762369001                                 
item map_key package_size_code                              
item.package_size_code string 01                            
item map_key package_size_intro_date                        
item.package_size_intro_date string 2015-05-01T00:00:00.000 
item map_key pediatric_indicator                            
item.pediatric_indicator string N                           
item map_key product_code                                   
item.product_code string 3690                               
.
.
.
```

I would like to have some way of knowing which data belongs to which object. Something like an index but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: This is a bit vague description. In situation where you are forced to use iterative json, the usage of the object needs to be known, because all objects can't be formed. Basically, objects should be consumed right away, so the answer depends on what you are trying to achieve? "some way of knowing which data belongs to which object" - this info is in the stream already, and you know when eg map starts and ends, so its possible to construct those objects one by one.

Comment: I see what you mean. I am trying to get each field that belongs to an object so that I can put them properly in a sqlite database. Eg, (package_size_code,fda_ther_equiv_code,fda_application_number....)

Comment: Thus they need to be obtained together as an "object" so that I can do the INSERT properly

Comment: I think my answer is good for the case then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, a better idea is to use `ijson.items`:

`item_gen = ijson.items(urllib.urlopen('https://data.medicaid.gov/resource/4qik-skk9.json?$limit=5'), 'item')`

then you can iterate over `item_gen` in a for-loop or with any itertools. For instance:

```
for item in item_gen:
    print(item)
```

I used Python 2, but I guess it's very similar in Python 3.

I've got this idea from [here](https://nbsoftsolutions.com/blog/processing-arbitrary-amount-of-data-in-python).

Comment: this looks interesting. Let me try it out. Will get back to you in a sec.

Comment: Very nice. This gives it to me in the structure I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's still a structure. That's what the various `start_`/`end_` events are for.  Given a data structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "object1",
    "color": "blue"
  },
  {
    "name": "object2",
    "color": "red"
  }
]
```

Your loop would generate the following stream:

```
 start_array None
item start_map None
item map_key name
item.name string object1
item map_key color
item.color string blue
item end_map None
item start_map None
item map_key name
item.name string object2
item map_key color
item.color string red
item end_map None
 end_array None
```

You use the `start_array` and `end_array` events to detect when you enter and exit an array, and you use the `start_map` and `end_map` events to detect when you enter and exit a map object.  This permits you to reconstruct the structure of the original data.

For example, here's a really dumb parser that would reconstruct the original data from the stream:

```
top = None
cur = None
cur_k = None
for prefix, event, value in parser:
    if event == 'start_array':
        top = []
    elif event == 'start_map':
        cur = {}
        top.append(cur)
    elif event == 'map_key':
        cur_k = value
    elif event == 'string':
        cur[cur_k] = value

print(top)
```

I say "really dumb" because it will only work with the particular data format you've shown in your example.  Any deviations from that would cause it to break.  You would probably want something more robust for actual use.

Comment: OHHH so that is what those are for. Ah I should have seen that, Thank you.